# VS2012 and JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I try to debug my JavaScript but the issue is more about VS2012. When I run the website debugger it creates some dynamic pieces of code which you can study while debugging but all the JavaScript code doesn't update once I run the debugger. In short it runs the same JavaScript code as the first time I saved the respective document containing the current code. It seems to me like a pretty huge bug, and therefore it also encouraged me to investigate it through the internet but I seem to be the only one to experience it.

Comment: Press ENTER in omni-bar instead of Click on Refresh button in IE

Comment: I close the browser and open a new one by click on the debugger button in VS2012. And the issue has been tested in both Chrome, IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you're trying to change the dynamic scripts. It doesn't work...

Instead of that, you should edit your source files and save them. If you do so, you don't need to stop the debugging process and start it again.

Just do edits in the source files and save them, then refresh your running page in browser and it works...

Comment: That is what I am doing, and I can see the change in the source files but as soon as I run the website it shows the dynamic scripts where no changes has been made.